# Error while sending encrypted data with Boost::asio::async_send_to

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, boost-asio, crypto++

I am developing an encrypted version of a realtime communication application. The issue I have is, that the encrypted data pakets sent to the receiver are faulty. An example from the error log: (hex encoded data, the original data is pure byte code).

sent: `262C1688215232656B5235B691826A21C51D37A99413050BAEADB81D8892493FC0DB519250199F5BE73E18F2703946593C4F6CEA396A168B3313FA689DE84F380606ED3C322F2ADFC561B9F1571E29DF5870B59D2FCF497E01D9CD5DFCED743559C3EE5B00678966C8D73EA3A5CD810BB848309CDF0F955F949FDBA618C401DA70A10C36063261C5DBAB0FC0F1`

received:    `262C1688215232656B5235B691826A21C51D37A99413050BAEADB81D8892493FC0DB519250199F5BE73E18F2703946593C4F6CEA396A168B3313FA689DE84F380606ED3C322F2ADFC561B9F1571E29DF5870B59D2FCF497E01D9CD5DFCED743559C3EE5B00CDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD`

This is the call of the send-method:

```
string encSendBuffer = sj->cipherAgent->encrypt(sj->dFC->sendBuffer, sj->dFC->sendBytes);    

char* newSendBuffer = new char[encSendBuffer.length() + 1];
strcpy(newSendBuffer, encSendBuffer.c_str());

sj->dFC->s->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(newSendBuffer, encSendBuffer.length()),
    *sj->dFC->f,
    boost::bind(&sender::sendHandler, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
)
```

`sj->dFC->s` is a UDP-Socket and `sj->dFC->f` is an UDP Endpoint.
The error code of the sendHandler is always `system: 0`

This is how I do the encryption using the Crypto++ library: (extract)

```
string cipherEngine::encrypt(char* input, int length)
{
    string cipher = "";

    CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(key, keyLength, iv);

    ArraySource as((byte*)input, length, true,
        new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
            new StringSink(cipher)
        )
    );

    return cipher;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Code of the receive function:

```
void receiver::receive(){
    int maxLength = 4096;

    sj->dFC->s->async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(input,maxLength),
                                   senderEndpoint, 
                                   boost::bind(&receiver::handleReceiveFrom, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

After the Data is received, it is stored in the char buffer `input` and decrypted in the `handleReceiveFrom` function.

Without encryption everything is fine. The number of bytes that are sended is always correct, on receiver side too. The length of de "CD"- blocks are quite random. I already checked the encryption and the decrypted data is the same as the original plain text.

Does any know where this behavior comes from?

Comment: The value `0xcd` is used by the Visual Studio debugger for uninitialized memory. There seems to be nothing wrong with the sending code (if `encSendBuffer` is a non-binary string (i.e. it only contains actual printable characters)), so the error might be in the code receiving the data. Can you please show it too?

Comment: You could also use a network sniffer, such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), to see that the data sent/received is the correct data.

Comment: Actually I can not guarantee that the content of `encSendBuffer` is readable. The input data of the encryption is pure byte code of the sound card. But it always looks good before it gets sended. I updated my question für the receive code.

Comment: Then you can't use `strcpy` as it will stop copying on the first zero-byte which it interprets as a string terminator. Use [`std::memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) instead.

Comment: *`char* newSendBuffer = new char[encSendBuffer.length() + 1];`* - since you are using C++, you should probably use a `vector`, `auto_ptr` or `array` (if C++11). There's no need to do this memory management yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that the erroneous data begins after the first null (0x00) value in your encrypted data array.  The following line:

```
strcpy(newSendBuffer, encSendBuffer.c_str());
```

...looks like it's only copying up to the data until that null byte into newSendBuffer.  The send function is sending that buffer contents just fine; the buffer just doesn't have the data you expect.  You'll need to load newSendBuffer in a different way, not using strcpy(), that can handle null bytes.  Try std::memcpy().

Comment: Good catch. I scanned his code for something like that, but did not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Joachim Pileborg and Jack O'Reilly! You are right indeed.

I changed my code from `strcpy(newSendBuffer, encSendBuffer.c_str());`

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < encSendBuffer.length(); i++)
{
    newSendBuffer[i] = encSendBuffer.at(i);
}
```

on sender and receiver side. It actually solved the problem. It is quite naive code but it does what it should.

`std::memcpy()` seems to be much more elegant and i will try it out.